# PGP encryption algor

Tags: encryption, cryptography, gnupg, pgp

I'm learning in detail how PGP system works but there are somethings that are not said everywhere I tried to look about it ;

According to [this Wikipedia diagram:](https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/4/4d/PGP_diagram.svg)

[image]

When we are encrypting, we use the Data and a Random key then we have the protected data ( the one with locket ).
Here's the first problem, how are these data crypted ? Which algorithm has been used ?

My second problem is at the last encryption ;
Locket data + Locket key = Encrypted message
Same thing here, how ? What did they used ?

Also, I read that somewhere, they are hashing the whole data so you can't change it or it will break everything, but when do they do that ?

Thanks in advance !

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because this is not about software development at all.

Comment: I'm making a program that do that so I needed some details about how it works to make a proper RSA algorithm.
And someone answered already so close it or whatever you want :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So your questions are:

1. How are the data and random key encrypted and which algorithm was used.
2. What algorithm was used to get an encrypted message from locket data + locket key.

> The message digest algorithm now used in PGP (Version 5.0 and later) is
>   called SHA, which stands for Secure Hash Algorithm, designed by the NSA
>   for the National Institute of Standards and Technology (NIST). SHA is a
>   160-bit hash algorithm.

That should answer both your questions.  Also checkout this [pdf](ftp://ftp.pgpi.org/pub/pgp/6.5/docs/english/IntroToCrypto.pdf)

SHA256 is actaully used in bitcoin, funny how things are related.  I remember there used to be free PGP downloads to play around with but sadly PGP is a symantec product now, progres....

Comment: "This session key works with a very secure, fast
conventional encryption algorithm to encrypt the plaintext; the result is
ciphertext"
That's exactly what I want to know, which algorithm ? 
Also on page 16 at the draw :
"Ciphertext + Encrypted session key"
What do they used to do this ?
According to your answer, this mean to be SHA ?

Comment: which algorithm ? SHA.  According to your answer, this mean to be SHA ? Yes

Comment: Take a look at :
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/GNU_Privacy_Guard#Overview
Why are there so many cipher if the SHA is supposed to be the used one ?

Comment: @AmatErasu Because PGP, like all good cryptosystems, isn't designed around a single primitive - it can use multiple. That way, if one is compromised, people can migrate to something more secure.

Comment: Thanks for the answer
Yes I understand that algorithm could be break so we can easily switch into other one way more secure.
But my original question was ;
A sent to B a PGP encrypted message using B Public Key
A used an algorithm that B don't know
When B receive the message from A, he can decrypt it even if A used an precise encryption.
How do B know the encryption?
So I though that in the encrypted session key, they were the algorithm used to decrypt the message.

Comment: @AmatErasu Algorithm used in PGP V5.0 or later is SHA.  Yes this can be changed if needed but to my knowledge, that is what it is.  Please correct me if I am wrong.

Comment: Yes this is correct !
I answered by myself about my question but thanks for the help everyone :)